# Div to extend to full height of window if its content is smaller

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with text content. I want the div height to extend to the full height of the browser window (view area) even when its content is not as high.

If the content makes it overflow the height of the window, I want the default behaviour. ie scroll bars appears AND the div height is not the same as the view area height.

I've put some code in on jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/bernard/gLjYg/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/bernard/gLjYg/2/). The yellow border should cover the whole window area unless you reduce the size of the window so that not all of the text is visible. In that case the text should be scrollable and the bottom or top border will be hidden.

index.html

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Think of a Nat Geo frame</h1><br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
​body, html {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

#container {
    border: 20px solid yellow;
}

.main {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2em;
}
```

The markup is not that important. I'd however like to avoid non semantic divs. I would also prefer a CSS based solution.​

Comment: Is this what you need : **http://jsfiddle.net/gLjYg/11/**

Comment: Sorry no. Billy Moat below has similar (same?) code. See my reply to him.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/gLjYg/10/

I had to add one more DIV as with height 100% on .main plus it's padding it made .main too tall.

Comment: That's not it. The bottom yellow border should be visible unless the text is scrolled. Also, no scroll bar appears when the text doesn't fit in the visible area (when one makes the height of the window smaller).

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you have to split the `border` and padding between two divs? if not, I'd use this:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

#container {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.main {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2em;
    border: 20px solid yellow;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why `body, html` won't stretch to full height though.

Comment: The markup is not that important. It's just that at my state of testing I had a container and main divs. As for your question, I believe you need to set body to 100% for container to also be 100%. But that wouldn't solve my problem. The container's border (yellow band) should extend beyond the visible area when the text is too large to fit in the visible area.

Comment: Hm, odd. I tried setting `body,html` to `height: 100%;` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this needs a very simple javascript fix! you'll need to first set the container's height after page load. After this you'll have to use a window resize event handler to keep checking if the new height of the window is smaller than the orignal height. If smaller, then make the container scrollable, while making sure the height has been adjusted as well. In case the window is resized back to its original height or bigger. this container will revert back to its original state.

```
<script>
var origHeight,container;
window.onload=function(){
origHeight= window.innerHeight;
container= document.getElementById("container");

};

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
 container.style.height=window.innerHeight+"px";  
if(window.innerHeight< origHeight){

container.style.overflowY="auto";
}
else{

container.style.overflowY="default";
}

});
</script>
```

this is all you need to solve the varying height problem!

here's the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/gLjYg/25/

Comment: wait, I didn't read the  last line about the top or bottom border's being hidden. Lemme check

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might be a few years late, but I ended up on this article and for anyone else who does this is my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/gLjYg/59/

First, I put all content into a single div:

```
<div class="main">
  <h1>Think of a Nat Geo frame</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Then, for easier to understand width/height measurements (includes padding, etc) I included border-box box sizing in the css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.main {
  border: 20px solid yellow;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Last, added the following javascript (with jQuery):

```
var $selector = $('.main');

setToWindowHeight($selector);
$(window).resize(function (){
  setToWindowHeight($selector);
});

function setToWindowHeight(selector) {
  selector.css({ 'min-height': $(window).innerHeight() });
}
```

On page load, and on resize, the .main div will have a min-height set equal to that of the window. The key here is min-height, so if the content is smaller than the window it will stretch to fit, but if the content is larger you will be able to scroll and nothing gets clipped out of view.

Comment: The hard part is to do it without javascript, just with CSS. Mind you CSS support and power has changed for the better in the years since I wrote the original question so I wouldn't be surprise to find out that it's simple to do nowadays.